# apt method to get the latest nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, apt, software-center, software-sources

The nvidia driver that I got from Ubuntu repository is 260.19.06 . I was having some problems with videos, so I checked the nvidia site, and the version available there was 260.19.44. Is there a way to get the same driver version using `apt-get` , or something similar, so that the driver remains managed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of using the most up-to-date version is following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual) manual . It has every step well explained, and some really good advices before doing it.
I seriously recommend you not to do it, and stick to the drivers in the official repositories, but if you are really experiencing issues, and you think that updating your Nvidia drivers will solve them, this is the best way of doing so.

Good luck!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way than manually installing the drivers is to add the Ubuntu X-Swat PPA; you can find the instructions here: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/06/how-to-install-nvidia-25635-display.html

But please note that it will install the latest released driver, which *may* not be very stable. With that said, I have had the PPA enabled on may laptop since I installed Maverick, because the default (260) driver was very dodgy while the current (270.29) is somewhat less so...

Finally a tip: check out ppa-purge (more info here: [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed-after-they-have-been-added-with-the-add-apt-repository-co)) if you want to revert the driver...

Best of luck

/N